# Understand the constructor and the assignement c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I’m a newbie in C++ and I come from C. The OOP is a whole new paradigm for me.

So I will ask a question on this stupid example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
public:
    int first;
    int second;
    Object ():first (0), second (0)
    {
        std::cout << "created1\n";
    }
    Object (int x, int y):first (x), second (y)
    {
        std::cout << "created2\n";
    }
};

int main ()
{
  Object s = { 1, 1 };  //Or  Object s(1,1);
  Object d;
  s = {2, 2};
  s = d;
  return 0;
}

/* Output:
    created2
    created1
    created2
*/
```

What are the differences in the two assignement (they are assignement?) before the return?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: The first line, despite using the `=` sign, is not actually using `operator=` or performing assignment of any kind. Rather, it is using [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to call the `Object(int x, int y)` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as `Object`'s compiler-generated `operator=` is concerned (since you did not implement your own), there is no difference.  It takes a `const Object &` reference as input, but it doesn't care where that `Object` comes from.

The only real difference in this code is in where that `Object` is coming from.

`s = {2, 2};` constructs a *temporary* `Object`, assigns the temporary to `s`, and then destroys the temporary.  The 2nd `created2` you see comes from that temporary.  The 1st `created2` comes from `Object s = { 1, 1 };`

`s = d;` assigns the existing `Object` named `d` to `s`. There is no temporary created, so no output here. The `created1` you see comes from `Object d;`.